Docker image not showing laravel logs to stderr stdout in docker logs
I'm using the nixpacks template from coolify (https://coolify.io/docs/applications/laravel/) to build a docker image and run it. Everything works fine, except I do not see the error logs in the terminal / when running docker logs.
My log channel is stack which is configured like
'stack' => [
  'driver' => 'stack',
  'channels' => ['single', 'stdout', 'syslog'],
  'ignore_exceptions' => false,
],

with
'stderr' => [
  'driver' => 'monolog',
  'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
  'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
  'formatter' => env('LOG_STDERR_FORMATTER'),
  'with' => [
    'stream' => 'php://stderr',
  ],
],

'stdout' => [
  'driver'  => 'monolog',
  'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
  'with'    => [
    'stream' => 'php://stdout',
  ],
  'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
],

LOG_LEVEL is set to debug. Running the application outside a docker container (starting with php artisan:serve) makes the logs appear as expected.
I found several resources and explanations for this (https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-get-laravel-logs-through-stdout-of-docker-container/121495)
If I understand it correctly, the logs do not appear because docker only shows the logs of the process with PID 1 - this the the start.sh in my case

The start.sh contains
#!/bin/bash

# Transform the nginx configuration
node /assets/scripts/prestart.mjs /assets/nginx.template.conf /etc/nginx.conf

# Start supervisor
supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf -n

The explanations makes sense, as I do see the supervisor logs about worker statuses.
HOWEVER, I did not find any solution or what I could do to make my laravel logs appear. I only ever found an explanation why they dont.
